# MySQL Query - Join/Union?

Tags: mysql

I have two queries which basically groups the home team for a selected month to get their statistics and then the other groups the away team for the selected month to get their statistics but the third query I want an overall set of statistics so the two of the combined but I am running into a brick wall with everything I try!

```
SELECT HomeTeam,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Played,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Home' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Won,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Draw' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Draw,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Away' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Lost,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Home' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),2) AS StrikeRate,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr <> 'TBP' THEN lsph ELSE 0 END),2) AS WinLSP,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr <> 'TBP' THEN lspd ELSE 0 END),2) AS DrawLSP,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr <> 'TBP' THEN lspa ELSE 0 END),2) AS LoseLSP
FROM Results_Football
GROUP BY HomeTeam
HAVING Played >= 20 AND WinLSP > 0
ORDER BY StrikeRate DESC
LIMIT 10

SELECT AwayTeam,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Played,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Away' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Won,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Draw' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Draw,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Home' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Lost,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr = 'Home' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),2) AS StrikeRate,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr <> 'TBP' THEN lspa ELSE 0 END),2) AS WinLSP,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr <> 'TBP' THEN lspd ELSE 0 END),2) AS DrawLSP,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Month = $FixSelMonth AND ftr <> 'TBP' THEN lsph ELSE 0 END),2) AS LoseLSP
FROM Results_Football
GROUP BY AwayTeam
HAVING Played >= 20 AND WinLSP > 0
ORDER BY StrikeRate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

So basically what I am trying to do is group by the teams and also get their statistics, if there a way of combining the two queries to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL to combine both the query.

Comment: UNION ALL will just give me the list from both, what I need is the calculations added together, so number of game Played when at home plus number played away and so on.